# Add dataframe to a list in R

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I have a list of dataframes (d) in R, all dataframes have the same columns

There is another list securities, and my task is to find the list of values (missing) that are in securities and not in names(d), to add empty dataframes to d with names as the values in missing, and the order in d should be the same as securities

What is the best approach

Comment: `setdiff(names(d), securities$values)`? That's my best guess without a reproducible example. If you need more help, please add a little bit of sample data and the desired result.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.